# If dividing by a variable gives a contradiction, does that imply that the variable must be zero?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, problem-solving, fake-proofs

Solving a problem, I got to a situation of contradiction after a lot of algebra and, looking back, I divided both sides of the equation by a variable that could be zero. I then assumed that the variable was zero, and turns out it was, and that is the way I solved the problem. I don't know if there was a better way, but it got me to the answer.

Is this considered a valid way of solving a problem? Meaning, if you divide both sides of an equation by a variable and it leads to a contradiction, does it *always* mean the variable equals zero? Would this be acceptable in a proof, for example?

Comment: When you divide by the variable, you are making an assumption that the variable is nonzero. If you later arrive at a contradiction, it could stem from this assumption, but it could also instead stem from any other assumptions you made before.

Comment: Yes. This is called proof by contradiction. You are not allowed to divide by $0$, so before you divide by $0$ you need to assume that the variable you divide by is non-zero. If you then reach a contradiction and this was the only assumption you made then this means that this assumption is false, and provides a proof that the variable is $0$. This is an acceptable proof, but you need to be explicit about what you are doing (e.g. before dividing by the variable, write: we assume that this variable is non-zero, which will lead to a contradiction).

Comment: That is a valid proof by contradiction. "*Assuming that $x \ne 0$ it follows that $\dots$ $1=0$, therefore the assumption must be false, so $x = 0$*".